# User data in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to figure which way is the best way of storing data acessible only for the user that is logged in.

For example: the classic `category` tutorial, but being acessible only to the user that created it.

My ideas at the moment are simple: creating an `User` model and making the other models(`Category`, for example) it's child.

Is there any clever way of doing this using ASP.NET MVC? When using the Identity we already have Users credentials for authorization, I just want to make data available only for the user that created it.

Comment: you can store the data against userid and then only retrieve by userid

Comment: Category could have a OWNERID field which stores the owner  (userID) of the record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When using the Identity we already have Users credentials for authorization, I just want to make data available only for the user that created it.

If you configure and integrate Identity in your application, you can try to establish a one-to-many relationship between the `Category` and `ApplicationUser` entities where many categories are associated with one ApplicationUser.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    //...
    //code here
    //...
}

public class Category
{
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }

    //...
    //other properties of category
    //...

    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can query data that specific user created based on UserId, like below.

```
//get user id of current logged-in user 
//then query data based on currentUserId

var category_list = _dbcontext.Categories.Where(c => c.UserId == currentUserId).ToList();
```